# Get listview position of inflated row

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

0When I click a button I inflate a row in a listview. The row I inflate contains two buttons and an imageview. With one of the buttons I can remove the inflated row from the listview. 
I use the following code.

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View vv = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_event_datetime, null);

ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) vv.findViewById(R.id.ivCancel);
ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            int i = ????
            ((LinearLayout) vv.getParent()).removeView(vv);
        }
    });  
View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.llAddActEventMoments);
((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(vv, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

When I click the image button ivCancel, is it possible to get the position in the listview of the removed row?

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement an `OnItemClickListener`, rather than an `onClickListener`.  See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) reference for more details.

Comment: I don't have the possibility to implement an OnItemClickListener on the ImageButton. Where do I have to implement the OnItemClickListener?

Comment: You set the onItemClickListener on your ListView.

Comment: Excuse me, but my I don't inflate the rows in a listview, but directly in a LinearLayout. I don't know if this is the correct way. But is it possible to get the position in a LinearLayout or should I rewrite my code?

Comment: From the sound of what you're doing, I think that using a ListView make more sense.  However, if you're adding items to a linear layout, you could always set unique ids to your new views, and traverse your view hierarchy to find the position.